# Spring SAML and OpenAM feredated SSO with ADFS

Tags: spring, adfs, openam, federated-identity

I want to use spring saml extension in my application the scenario is as follows
1) We have a ADFS(abc.domain.com) other organization installed on windows 2008 R2 Enterprise.
2) Planning to install OpenAM(xyz.domain.com) as An IDP for our organization which will       communicate to the ADFS(abc.domain.com) in a federation.(reason for this is to isolate the configuration and maintaining metadata in separate environment/machine )
3)Our application deployed on other tomcat servers which will have the spring saml extension embedded into it.

Basically the end goal is to login from ADFS(abc.domain.com) to our application with no login page.

Please guide me if any one has worked this kind of the situation.

Comment: Why do you need OpenAM as IdP? ADFS can act as SAMLv2 IdP as well, then just use Spring SAML SP.

Otherwise OpenAM needs to act as IdP proxy.

Comment: Yeah you are absolutely  right is there tutorials for this kind of set up please let me know

Comment: adding to the above Comments i am ok in adding srping SAML AS SP but we have different clients and all of them need SSO but they do have different IDP's

Comment: someone created 

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Configuring+OpenAM+IDP+Proxy+with+ADFS+and+remote+Service+Provider

but I have not verified it myself